# Concatenate multiple rows into single rows and count the concatenated rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table A:

[image]

and I want an output like this:

[image].

I want to concatenate multiple rows into a single row as well as I want to count how many rows are concatenated..

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 4):

use `stuff()`

```
select id,  stuff(( select concat( ',', name) from tablename b where a.id= b.id
for xml path('')),1,1, ''),count(*) as cnt
    from tablename a
    group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(50))


INSERT INTO #Temp(ID, [NAME])VALUES(1,'ABC')
INSERT INTO #Temp(ID, [NAME])VALUES(1,'EFG')
INSERT INTO #Temp(ID, [NAME])VALUES(2,'HIJ')
INSERT INTO #Temp(ID, [NAME])VALUES(2,'JKL')
INSERT INTO #Temp(ID, [NAME])VALUES(3,'MNO')
```

First Created a table....

```
SELECT t.ID,STUFF(
(
SELECT ',' + s.NAME
FROM #Temp s
WHERE s.ID = t.ID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS NAME,COUNT(t.ID) AS COUNT

FROM #Temp AS t
GROUP BY ID
```

**USE Stuff()**